# Why is my CSS not working on my LAMP server?

Tags: html, css, apache, lamp

So I just finished working on a site on my computer, and I put it on a flash drive and put it in my public_html folder on my server. When I type in http://localhost/ I get my index page but the css is gone and all the images are gone.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Look into the page's source code to see what path the CSS style sheet is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this question is from years ago. For those interested, the problem was due to permissions on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have put the right path for your css and images.

Comment: yes the path is right. When I open the html file from the folder on my computer it works but when I go to http://localhost/index.html it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that inside your html, the path to your css is correct.
  link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"

Your href="mystyle.css" should have a correct reference by using ..(dot-dot) just like "../folderName" in case your css file is one or more directory away from you main folder.

Comment: yes I have that, when I open the html file in it's folder on my computer everything works but when I go to http://localhost/index.html the css and images don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all that you need to do is clear your browsers cache, which will store the pages current state and will sometimes ignore any new changes to the css and sometimes even images until the cache is cleared.